# Make bootstrap navbar scrollable with lot of items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working on a site, which has a lot of nav-items. But now, I can't make the navbar perfectly working. Some nav-items goes away if I toggle the dropdown on a smaller screen when I add a "max-height" property to the navbar-nav. By default, it's not scrollable, so in that case more items go away, and be invisible in the UI. I really don't know what should I do now. Can somebody help me?

Here's my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" >
      Navbar
    </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-light" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li><li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Drobesz/tc8zy0hL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the `navbar-collapse` element has a larger height as the view screen.

A possible solution is to use `view height` ([check out this example](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_unit_vh)) in combination with `overflow-y`:

```
.navbar-collapse {
    max-height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

The updated fiddle can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tc8zy0hL/8/).

Answer (score 0):

Just give overflow : scroll; in the .navbar class.